# How to get the id of selected radio button in android?

Tags: android

I am working on quiz application in android. We have created **Select.java** page which displays the questions and options(with radio buttons) from sqlite database. Also we created a **header.java** file for displaying buttons i.e back and next buttons for the Select.java page.

[image]

Here we need to get the selected radio button id and need to send that to Header class. Because header class consists of the next button onclick action. Once the next button is clicked the selected radio button value has to be stored in arraylist. We created radio buttons in Select.java class. So my question is how to get the selected radio button id into that next button click action. Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-radiobutton-example

Comment: Hi I have already gone through that link. But here our doubt is we have created our radio buttons in Select.java and our button click action is in Header class. Now how can i get the selected radio button id's? Please help me.

Comment: why don't you post your code snippet, to get solution quickly..

Comment: make sure to add your layout-xml file if you use one (which you should:D)

Comment: you need to carry this radio button  click next page or u wanna save it on ur header class. ?  Please explain a  bit thanx

Comment: i got ur point Please Post the code !!

Answer (score 8):

**Your layout xml file should be like this**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RadioGroup 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RadioButton 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/option1"
       android:text="Option1"
    />
    <RadioButton 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/option2"
       android:text="Option2"
    />
    <RadioButton 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/option3"
       android:text="Option3"
    />
    <RadioButton 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/option4"
       android:text="Option4"
    />
    <RadioButton 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/option5"
       android:text="Option5"
    />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Add the below ode in your Activity**

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
            {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                String text = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: select.java code http://pastebin.com/xY86sZFx and header.java http://pastebin.com/XFwBbhQ7

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a old question but i don't see my answer in anywhere and **i found it more simple** than others..

so here we go:

```
int myRadioChecked;
if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RADIO_BUTTON).getId()) {
  /**Do Stuff*/
  //ex.: myRadioChecked = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.MyRadioGroup);

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(selectedId));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In RadioGroup Class you can use method [getCheckedRadioButtonId();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId())

```java
RadioGroup rg = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group. Upon empty selection, the returned value is `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, just add one more member variable in UserBO to store selected answer.

```
Class UserBO {

private int userID;
private String userName;
private String question;
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;

private int answerID;

//create getter and setters for above member variables
}
```

then within onclick listener of Adapter class, do like as following

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup,
                int radioButtonID) {
        switch(radioButtonID) {
                case R.id.option1:
                       listItem.setAnswerID(1);
            break;
        case R.id.option2:
                listItem.setAnswerID(2);
            break;

                 }
        }
    });
```

then change your header constructor to receive userarraylist (which contains user details with answer)

```
ArrayList<USerBO> userList;
Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, ArrayList<UserBO> userALt) {
userList = userAL;
}

//on next button click

onclick() {
    for(UserBO userObj: userList) {
        if (userObj.getAnswerID != 0)
         Log.d("AnswerID", userObj.getAnswerID);
    }
}
```

it just like sudo code.. i hope this will help u..

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id of selected button by the following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345451/how-to-get-id-of-selected-radio-button-in-a-radio-group).Here

```
int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

will give you the id.Also you can to Toast to see id like this

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Id of radio button"+position+, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This will pop up - "Id of radio button you clicked is 0" if you clicked first button.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way:

```
RadioButton button = findViewById(v.getId());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) In the future, I suggest you give us a better description of why your approach is the best one, it helps other people learn. Thanks!