# Java RadioButton BMI Calculator (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building my frist Android App to a school project. It's based on a BMI calculator which the last result will be influenced by the Gender (Male/Female).

The main calculation is working but after checking a lot of tutorials i can't adapt the codes i found to my app.

```
package com.example.calculadorimc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
        // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button

        if (view.getId() == R.id.botaoCalcular) {

         // get the references to the widgets
         EditText editPeso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPeso);
         EditText editAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
         TextView imcView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcView);

         // get the users values from the widget references

         float peso = Float.parseFloat(editPeso.getText().toString());
         float altura = Float.parseFloat(editAltura.getText().toString());

         // calculate the bmi value

         float imcValue = calcularIMC(peso, altura);

         // interpret the meaning of the bmi value
         String imcInterpretation = interpretIMC(imcValue);

         // now set the value in the result text

         imcView.setText(imcValue + "-" + imcInterpretation);
        }
       }

       // the formula to calculate the BMI index

       private float calcularIMC (float peso, float altura) {

        return (float) (peso / (altura * altura));
       }


       // interpret what BMI means
       private String interpretIMC(double imcValue) {

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            if(RadioButton.R.id.radioMasc){
                         if (imcValue < 16) {
                             return "Magreza Grave";
                            } else if (imcValue < 18.5) {

                             return "Magreza Leve";
                            } else if (imcValue < 25) {

                             return "Saudável";
                            } else if (imcValue < 30) {

                             return "Sobrepeso";
                            } else if (imcValue < 35){
                             return "Obesidade Grau I";
                            } else if (imcValue < 40){
                             return "Obesidade Grau II";
                            } else {
                                return "Obesidade Grau III";
                            }}
                    break;
            if(RadioButton.R.id.radioFem){
                    if (checked){
                        if (imcValue < 16) {
                         return "Magreza Grave";
                        } else if (imcValue < 18.5) {

                         return "Magreza Leve";
                        } else if (imcValue < 25) {

                         return "Saudável";
                        } else if (imcValue < 30) {

                         return "Sobrepeso";
                        } else if (imcValue < 35){
                         return "Obesidade Grau I";
                        } else if (imcValue < 40){
                         return "Obesidade Grau II";
                        } else {
                            return "Obesidade Grau III";
                        }}
                    }
                    break;
       }    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I decided to clen the app with my old experiments and only let the logic of the code to show the results influenced by the gender.

Here's my .XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgSexo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbMasculino"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/radioMasc" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbFeminino"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radioFem" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alturaView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alturaView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAltura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/editAltura" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pesoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pesoView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPeso"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/editPeso" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="#111111" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botaoCalcular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="calculateClickHandler"
        android:text="@string/botaoCalcular" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imcView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/imcView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: very good! but what is the question now?

Comment: I don't know how to get the checked radiobutton to associate his id to the following condition! The code above is wrong and incomplete!

Answer (score 0):

```
 // get selected radio button from radioGroup
    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

 // find the radiobutton by returned id
    radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

//  radioSexButton.getText()  if you want the text
```

i.e. To get the id and associate radio button

Comment: Seems to be simple!
Don't i need to create a variable called radioSexButton

Comment: And how should i express that on the if condition?

if(radioSexButton = "radioMasc"){
}

Comment: check the value of radioSexButton.getText()

Comment: Something like this?    if(radioSexButton.getText().radioMasc){


Or This??


if(radioSexButton.R.id.radioMasc){

Comment: you got the id of the button selected, compare it with the the text or id of your radio button...that should be simple and easy. Another option is using onCheckedChangedListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307052/how-to-get-the-id-of-selected-radio-button-in-android