# How to get id of selected radio button in a radio group

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am making a quiz app in which I have a viewPager which has 15 pages in it having 1 question each and a submit button at the last page.Now I want to get the Maximum number of option selected among 15 questions.
Below is my code

QuestionPagerFragment.java:

```
public class QuestionPagerFragment extends Fragment {   

    protected View mView;
    String pageData[];  //Stores the text to swipe.
    String optionData[];//Stores the option data.
    int rid;
    RadioGroup group;
    String ans;
    String ans1;
    String ans2;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pageData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desserts);

        optionData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);

        group = (RadioGroup)mView.findViewById(R.id.group);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                checkedId=group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rid=checkedId;
                save();
            }
        });
               ((TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textMessage)).setText(pageData[getArguments().getInt("pos")]);
        if(getArguments().getInt("pos") == 14) {
            ((Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.submitbtn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.submitbtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v){
                       System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-------------"+MainActivity.FLAG_A);
                       System.out.println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB-------------"+MainActivity.FLAG_B);
                       System.out.println("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC-------------"+MainActivity.FLAG_C);
                       System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD-------------"+MainActivity.FLAG_D);   
                       click();
       }                   
                });
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++){
            ((RadioButton) group.getChildAt(i)).setText(optionData[(getArguments().getInt("pos")*4)+i]);
        }      
    }
    public void save() {

           if(rid==2131034179){
               MainActivity.FLAG_A++;                  
           }
           else if(rid==2131034180){
               MainActivity.FLAG_B++;    
           }
           else if(rid==2131034181){
               MainActivity.FLAG_C++;    
           }
           else if(rid==2131034182){
               MainActivity.FLAG_D++;    
           }
    }
    public void click(){
           ans = String.valueOf(Math.max(MainActivity.FLAG_A, MainActivity.FLAG_B));
           ans1 = String.valueOf(Math.max(Integer.parseInt(ans), MainActivity.FLAG_C));
           ans2 = String.valueOf(Math.max(Integer.parseInt(ans1), MainActivity.FLAG_D));
           String a = ans2;
           SharedPreferences prefss = getActivity().getSharedPreferences( "idValue", 0 );
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefss.edit();
           editor.putString( "idValue", a);
           editor.commit();
           Log.e("Shared Pref","-----------------------" +a);
    }
}
```

And MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    String pageData[];  //Stores the text to swipe.
    String optionData[];//Stores the option data.
    LayoutInflater inflater;    //Used to create individual pages
    ViewPager vp;   //Reference to class to swipe views
    Button submit;
    public static int FLAG_A;
    public static int FLAG_B;
    public static int FLAG_C;
    public static int FLAG_D;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pageData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desserts);

        optionData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        vp.setAdapter(new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = new QuestionPagerFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("que", pageData[position]);
            b.putInt("pos", position);
            f.setArguments(b);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pageData.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can get it like this

```
int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);

// If you want position of Radiobutton
int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

Complete code

```
//complete code..
//rgp is your radio group
rgp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I have one more doubt as I am flipping the screens flags are incrementing though I am not reselecting the radio buttons

Comment: No I want flag should be incremented only once means if a user visits the page again but doesnt change the answer then flag of selected option shouldnt be incremented as it is happening right now

Comment: that you need to check if user not change anything. flag will remain same. It should be in changing of fragment.