# Radiogroup checked id getting wrong value -1

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to access the `RadioButton` from the `RadioGroup`,

```
int selectedId = radioFeeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

radioFeeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
```

I am getting `selectedId` value -1. That's why application get crashed.

Comment: make sure  you are selecting at least one radio button from the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure you are  selecting at least one Radio button from the group.

[See the Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId())

Your code is correct,

```
int selectedId = radioFeeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

radioFeeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
```

> > If you are already selecting the `RadioButton` then **clean the project & Rebuild it again** it should work if you are accessing `RadioGroup` correctly from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 radioFeeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    int radioButtonID = radioFeeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    View radioButton = radioFeeGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                    int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                }
            });
```

**Check this examples**

[How to get the id of selected radio button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307052/how-to-get-the-id-of-selected-radio-button-in-android)

[How to get id of selected radio button in a radio group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345451/how-to-get-id-of-selected-radio-button-in-a-radio-group)