# Is there are a way to display text from UNSELECTED radio buttons?

Tags: java, android

I am working in android, I am wondering if there is a way to append a TextView with texts from the radio buttons that were not selected. As a list that would look like "Not selected: Item A, Item b" etc.

I wanted to try something like this:

```
 if (radioButtonId == 1) {
        notSelected.append(optionsContainer.getCheckedRadioButtonId(3).getText().toString());
```

But I am presented with an error that reads

```
getCheckedRadioButtonId() in RadioGroup cannot be applied to int()
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm not even sure this is something that can be done

Comment: consider read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955546/4628993

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtons can be selected once at time, so you can't "decide" which index you want check.

```
getCheckedRadioButtonId()
```

return the view id that is actually selected.

Docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#getCheckedRadioButtonId()

> Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group. Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.

As i say on comments consider read https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955546/4628993